# How to return to previously opened tab on back button press

Tags: android

I have a TabLayout with 3 sections. Each section contains list of items.

When I click item on second section, I start new activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondDetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside of SecondDetailActivity I have an action bar with back button.
And I handle click of back button like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**My problem is:**

When I click device's back button, the selected tab of the tablayout is *Second* tab. But when I click on action bar navigation button, the selected tab is *First* tab.

How can I make action bar's behavior same as device's back button?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return `true` while your case is `android.R.id.home`
like

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution helped me